# VSCode is not displaying the JSDoc define within an imported JS Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, jsdoc

I am having a problem in vscode where I can not see the defined jsdocs in a js class when importing that class in another js file. Not when hovering or using the vscode shortcuts.

> ./src/person/index.js

```
/**
* This is a person class.
*/
export default class Person{

    /**
    * Person constructor
    * @param {string} Name of the person
    * @param {number} Age of the person
    */
    constructor(name, age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

> ./src/index.js

```
import { Person } from './src/person/index.js'

const jim = new Person("him", 88) // jsdoc is not recognized
```

Comment: upvote this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174229

Answer (score 0):

> ./src/index.js

```js
import { Person } from './src/person/index.js'

const jim = new Person("jim", 88)
```

`jim` is not string. You should change `"jim"`

Comment: not the issue. I was trying to give example. But before saving anything or running anything. I want to hover over "new Person()" and see the JSDoc for the class inside "./src/index.js". Fyi JSDoc of Person class works inside './src/person/index.js'